# How can I view console.log() statements when deploying a Next.js app on Vercel?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, vercel

I have a Next.js app deployed on Vercel, and I need to view the console.log() statements when any server-side or client-side rendered page is called. I have noticed that I can see these logs when running the app locally in my terminal, but I cannot see them in Vercel's function logs.

I am specifically interested in viewing these logs to debug an issue where a page that works on my local system is resulting in a 504 error when deployed to Vercel. The page's API call never takes more than 3 seconds.

What are some ways to view these console logs in Vercel, or is there an alternative way to debug the 504 error that I am experiencing?

However, I am not able to see these logs in Vercel's function logs. Is there any other way to view these logs?

[image]

but I think this happens on a site called "favicon.ico`

This favicon.ico link opens/works on the local system next to dev mode. but in Vercel, this gives 504 errors.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: are you not able to see the logs on your vercel dashboard?

Comment: Could it be that ur base url is not defined? The favicon is normally present in your public folder.

Comment: i can see only the build logs. this build success. but i face issue only when i call the page. so this time i can't see my logs. 

https://vercel.com/guides/where-are-vercel-logs

Comment: i added fave icon in my public filter.  and this favicon will come dynamic.

this is my next code.
# _app.js

```js
<Head>
  <link
    rel="shortcut icon"
    href={
      getStrapiMedia(favicon.data.attributes?.url) ?? "../public/favicon.ico"
    }
  />
</Head>;

```
also i put `favicon.ico` in public folder